# Sine function in pgfplots and MATLAB. Why are different results obtained?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I did the graph (view image) of the absolute value of sine function in pgfplots and MATLAB. Why are different results obtained?

[image: pgfplots - MATLAB]

pgfplots:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]

    \begin{axis}[
    domain = 0:2*pi,
    yticklabels={-2,-1,0,1,2},
    axis lines = middle,
    axis on top = true,
    grid = major,
    grid style = {dashed, line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30, /pgfplots/on layer=axis background},

    ]
    
    \addplot+[no marks, color=blue] {abs(sin(deg(x)))};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

MATLAB:

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
z = abs(y);

plot(x,z,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','blue');
```

Comment: Because `pgfplots` has a default number of samples within the given domain, and that is set to 25. So you don't get a value at the middle minimum. Set `samples=200` or something.

Comment: Also the y tick labels are wrong. You set the labels without setting the values, so you have for example label 0 on value 0.2... and so on.

Comment: Isn't this question exactly the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357931/?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use more samples to make sure that pi is one of the x-values used to calculate the y-values.

The number of samples can be set using an optional argument to the `\begin{axis}` command.

```
\begin{axis}[samples=1000,...]
```

Comment: As I supposed, i had to expand the domain. Ty Anders.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems here.

First off, the number of sample is [too small by default for your case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310502/strange-behavior-of-absx-in-pgf-plots) --- you should ask for more, and, if you want to get the value in the middle of the domain, [use an odd number of them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357931/how-can-i-repair-this-graph-when-the-graph-is-not-continuous-at-the-origin).

```
samples = 101,
```

Then, you use `xticklabels` which puts the given labels at the (automatically calculated) ticks position... you should almost never use `xticklabels` without an explicit `xtick`.  In this case, they are not needed.

Additionally (but this is a matter of style) I think that the graph is better with a bit of breathing, and indicating the coordinates (0,0); both effects are  achieved removing `axis lines = middle`. So:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[
    domain = 0:2*pi,
    samples = 101,
    axis on top = true,
    grid = major,
    grid style = {dashed, line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30, 
    /pgfplots/on layer=axis background},
]
\addplot+[no marks, color=blue] {abs(sin(deg(x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and to show the `xticklabels` thing, [if you add](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249953/locating-tick-marks-at-integral-multiples-of-pi-2):

```
xtick = {0, 1.5708, ..., 7},
xticklabels = {$0\mathstrut$, $\pi/2$, $\pi\mathstrut$, $3\pi/2$, $2\pi\mathstrut$},
```

you have:

[image]

Comment: Note: it's `axis x line` (not _lines_)