# Pgfplots and MATLAB provide different results

Tags: pgfplots, matlab

I need to plot a function using pgfplots, but the result is different from the expected. The domain should be `0:1`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
        \addplot[domain=0:55, samples=1001]{((sqrt((1 -cos(2*pi*x))^2+sin(2*pi*x)^2))^4)^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the domain had to be set to 55 in order to show the whole function. While the MATLAB code being the following:

```
x=0:0.01:1;
plot(x,((sqrt((1-cos(2*pi*x)).^2+sin(2*pi*x).^2)).^4).^2)
```

I have read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359654/sine-function-in-pgfplots-and-matlab-why-are-different-results-obtained) but it did not help this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matlab's `sin` and `cos` assume radians as input, while `pgf`'s `sin` and `cos` assume degrees. For `pgfplots` you can add `trig format=rad` to the `\addplot` options to get the same behaviour as Matlab, then `domain=0:1` works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=1001, trig format=rad]{((sqrt((1 -cos(2*pi*x))^2+sin(2*pi*x)^2))^4)^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```