# PGFPlots and Maple create different plots

Tags: pgfplots

I try to create parametric plot using `PGFPlots` and found out that the plot which created with `PGFPlots` is different to plot created with `Maple`. While in `Maple` I substitute `t` variable values from 0..0.15 range using PGFPlots i have to substitute values from 0:0.003 range to save the same view of curve.

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title = Movement,
    xlabel = {$x$},%xmin=0,xmax=0.003,
    ylabel = {$y$},%ymin=0,ymax=1e-5,
    variable = \t,
    samples = 200]

   \addplot[blue,domain=0:0.003](
     {1*cos(0.79)*t},
     {-(49/10)*t^2+1*sin(0.79)*t});
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I force `PGFPlots` to produce plot in right range?

Comment: pgfplots work with degrees

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to PGFPlots and didn't know this feature. I have to learn package manual carefully.

Comment: You can do the conversion to radians manually, or use `trig format=rad`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416335/pgfplots-and-matlab-provide-differente-results/416336#416336

Comment: Ok. Thank you for trick. Can anyone tell me why PGFPlots takes arguments of trigonometric functions in degrees by default while most of other math tool in radians?

Comment: I think that comes from `pgf`, so it's more a question of why `pgf` uses degrees. I don't know the answer though.